# Getting all the records via api

Tags: api, pagination, azure-data-factory

I have open api mention in link below

https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/help-api

Considering I need to extract all the records for below api query for city= Baltimore
https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?version=2.1&city=baltimore

Using limit and skip

https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?version=2.1&city=baltimore&limit=200&skip=1000

Problem is by using skip and limit,I can get only 1200 records in 6 iteration skipping 0,200,400,600,800 and Max 1000 for each Max limit of 200 as mention in [website](https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/help-api).

I am sure it has more than 1200 record, Can someone please help me how to get all the data for city= Baltimore .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to pass the offset value dynamically in the URL and increment the offset value each time by looping in until activity.
Loop the `until` activity, until the response of the API request is empty.

Example:

```
@concat('https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?version=2.1&city=baltimore&limit=200&skip=',variables('skip_value'))
```

You can also use pagination to provide the offset range. Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#example-1-variables-in-queryparameters) for more information.

Comment: Firstly, thanks so much for your response. But if you see the documentation in url below the max skip allowed is 1000 . URL:https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/help-api .